# Clone dropdown vs Clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm having the following code for clone a textbox:

HTML:

```
 <TextBox id="numericTextBoxClone"/>
```

jQuery code:

```
var numericTextBoxClientID = '<%= numericTextBoxClone.ClientID%>';
var clonedElement = $('#' + numericTextBoxClientID).clone().attr('id', 'id_'                      + item.ID);
$('#id_' + item.ID).show();
var element = $('<div/>');
element.append(clonedElement);
```

Clon is working fine - I can see the new textbox on my page,
but when I do the same for a dropdown it doesn't work, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clone the dropdown use the following code snippet :-

**HTML**

```
<div id="clone" class="new-dropdown">
        <select class="dropdown-select" name="categories">
            <option></option>
            <option value="1">val 1</option>
            <option value="2">val 2</option>
            <option value="3">val 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <a href="#" class="add-another-cat smallest" style="">Add another category</a>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.add-another-cat').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var $orDiv = $('.new-dropdown:last').after($('#clone').clone().removeAttr('id').show());

        });

    });
```

Hope this will work for you.
Thanks.